Vernier Caliper Measurement - Formula for Measurement
My doubt is regarding the formula for measurement using a vernier caliper. In my class we were taught the following formula:
$Reading = MSR + n(LC)$ (p)
(here MSR stands for main scale reading and LC for least count, n shows that the nth division of the vernier scale coincides with some division of the main scale)
(q) I also know that this formula won't remain valid if we take a vernier caliper with the main scale having more divisions than the vernier scale for a fixed length.
Now I'm considering a situation in which the number of vernier scale divisions are more than the number of main scale divisions for a fixed length. There is no error either.
I was trying to intuitively come up to this formula (p).
Looking at the main scale I know that the length of the object will be slightly greater than the MSR. Now I have to simply work to find that reading. Next, I find the coinciding division.
Now if we were to take it in the form of variables, let's assume that there are 'a' divisions of the main scale and 'b' divisions of the vernier scale. (here I'm talking about the divisions between the object and the coincident division)
$Ma - bV = x$ (the tiny length that has to be added to MSR). (1)
M,V: distance between two divisions in main and vernier scale respectively.
If a = b we can say that:
$b(M-V) = x$
Where b is equal to n in (a) as it is the $bth$ division that coincides.
n(LC) = x
But does this mean that a and b are always equal? I know we don't use the formula when the number of divisions of the vernier scale are fewer than the number of divisions in the main scale for a fixed length. In that case a and b turn out to be different. But can't there be cases in this scenario where a and b are unequal? What do we do? Or is my approach flawed?
I got to know from the other question that M - V = LC is a formula meant to be used for standard vernier calipers with the main scale having n divisions and the vernier scale having (n+1) divisions for a fixed length. So is formula (p) not always valid even in situations excluding (q) (q:  involving more divisions in main scale than vernier scale for a fixed length). If it's a standard vernier caliper with n and n+1 divisions for main and vernier scales respectively, a and b in (1) will always be equal and the formula can be proven.
Note: A similar question exists, as pointed out by someone. That question mainly deals with LC. Here I have a slightly different question involving the reading. I mainly want to know more about the formula for taking a reading on a vernier caliper. LC is a part of it and clarifies a portion of it, but I'm still confused with the rest. I understand it's connected to that, but those answers don't thoroughly clarify my doubt.


Does this answer your question? Least count of Vernier

You agreed to the duplicate. If you have another question, please post it as another question.

@entropy I said another question. I didn't tell you to copy and paste the same question again. You've already submitted it for review so wait for it to complete.

@VincentThacker Oh, okay, sorry.
